# How can I store images and strings locally on Swift

Tags: swift

I'm making an app where the user can take a picture and add a title and description. But now I need to store the picture and the titles. I’ve tried making an object that contains title, description and image properties.

When it’s done I save an array of custom objects with the information on it with UserDefaults. My idea is showing in another view a table view with all the content and pictures the user has taken on the cells. I tried getting back the information with user defaults. It was working well until the user saves too many pictures. When the viewController with the tableview loads, then my app gets slower, and eventually it crashes.

I suppose the problem is when I load all the array with all custom objects, all the pictures are loaded into memory although they aren’t used and displayed for users. So I think it isn’t the best way to make what I want to make.

Is there any way better to make what I’m making or store data more efficiently and use it in tableview without using all the memory of the device?

I’m making the app from 0 again.

Can you show me how to store data and images efficiently?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When storing this kind of data, you have 2 options (In fact you have more than 3 options, but saving image to the disk is IMHO complicated for this.) -

1. UserDefaults
2. Database like CoreData/Realm/FireBase...

The first one is recommended when there is not much data to save... For operating with more data, I would use database - CoreData...

For you operation you can use CoreData and NSFetchedResultsController (which is designed especially for fetching objects from the database)...

you can read the FetchedResultsController doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller)... and core data basics [here](https://blog.bobthedeveloper.io/beginners-guide-to-core-data-in-swift-3-85292ef4edd)

Wish you best luck!

Comment: There are several more options than UserDefaults and CoreData. The pictures can be written as files. The data can be written to files in various formats. Certainly UserDefaults should not be used to store pictures or anything other than little bits of information.

Comment: @rmaddy why would you want to save these data into files? It just complicates things in matter of this question

Comment: Huh? How is writing an image to a file complicated?

Comment: Why would you wanna save the datas into files and then load them back and proceed with all these unsafe ways to search for files in directories, when you can have one persistent storage and manage it from there...

Comment: I'm not saying not to use CoreData. I said not to use UserDefaults to save pictures and other large data. I simply pointed out that there are other options besides the two you listed. A good answer points out all options. There are pros and cons to all of the options. Point them out. Let readers decide which option best suits their needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for permanently storing user data on the device such that it will survive app and phone restarts.  NSUserDefaults typically is for small amounts of data, such as user preferences.

When it comes time to store a lot of data, in particular big binary objects like photos, you need to decide which design you want to use.  One option:

- store all the photos in one directory in your apps documents and then use some simple lookup store (perhaps Core Data, or SQLite, or even a flat file) to index the photos and their metadata.  Or if you don't care about indexing you can read the list of file names from the directory and sort them by time.

The other problem you are maybe having is that you are trying to load *all* of the photos at once for the user.  As you have discovered, once you have more than a handful of photos this system falls apart.  You need some mechanism to load only a few photos at a time, preferably only the ones the user needs to be displayed at that moment.

So, for example, if you are displaying the photos in a tableview, you want to only load the 10-15 photos that are visible in the table at any given time.